# File searching changed in windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

You know how when you press a letter on your keyboard while in a directory, it automatically scrolls to files that start with said letter. This has changed and I can no longer do it, instead if I press a letter it automatically begins a file search for files with that letter. This in turn make the whole process much slower.

Example:
I am in a directory with 3 files: A, B and C. I press B on my keyboard to go to that file, but instead windows types B in the search bar on the top right of the file manager.

How do I change this?

Comment: Use Far manager, as variant: http://www.farmanager.com/download.php?l=en